# Is it possible to use Karate with pycharm?

Tags: python, rest, unit-testing, pycharm, karate

Is it possible to use Karate with pycharm? If not, what is the best alternative to Karate for python tornado REST APIs?
https://github.com/intuit/karate

Comment: What is Karate?

Comment: @StephenRauch A REST API testing framework, I put the link in the question

Comment: From my extensive viewing of kung foo movies karate and pythons go together fairly well...

Comment: @PeterThomas done

Answer (score 1):

Karate can be used to test *any* web-service that works over HTTP. Teams are currently using it for JSON, XML, GraphQL and SOAP.

In my opinion technology does not matter, in fact Karate's syntax is 80% "language neutral" and 20% JS. Java is optional. And it fits into all CI tools because it generates JUnit formal XML reports and even HTML reports.

If you are choosing not to use Karate because the server is implemented in Python or if the dev-team is supposedly more "comfortable" with Python, I personally do not agree with that decision.

PyCharm (if you are referring to the IDE) is made by JetBrains, the makers of IntelliJ - which has excellent built-in support for Cucumber and hence Karate syntax also. I have not checked, but it is highly likely that PyCharm supports Cucumber syntax also.

EDIT: I'll add a few more options, the [stand-alone executable](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar) which works well in combo with [Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/intuit/karate#ide-support) for which [dedicated plugins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kirkslota.karate-runner) have started to appear.

For a video of what the dev-experience looks like for someone who is coming from a JavaScript background, see this [10 minute lightning talk with demos](https://youtu.be/If9V-tG_gRs).

Comment: Do you know how to use in PyCharm?

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi sorry, I haven't used PyCharm. I don't think it is too much to ask for Karate test developers to use Eclipse. In fact even a plain text editor is sufficient.

Comment: As I've search I've seen that all installation procedures are related to Java and maeven or spring. I there an installation of karate for my purpose?

Comment: yes, if installing eclipse is an option for you. read the doc.

Comment: It does not make sense from a user experience perspective to say users have to use eclipse when they use another IDE instead. It's a very good way to discourage people from using the tool.